# Orientação a objeto com jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, orientação-a-objetos

Ja li várias coisas sobre isso,e cheguei a esta conclusão, exemplo:

```
   var classe = function () {
        var metodo = function () {
            return 0;
        }
        return {
            init: function () {
                metodo();
            }
        };
    }();

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
       classe.init();
    });
```

Primeira:

> Essa é a forma correta de instanciar classes/metodos em javascript ? Se não, como seria a forma correta ?

Segunda:

Métodos jQuery são chamados de forma cadenciada:

```
$('#elemento').show().html('<html></html>').append('<div></div>').addClass('exemplo');
```

> O jQuery de forma nativa (sem fazer funções, apenas os métodos originais) pode ser considerado uma orientação a objeto ?

Comment: Os métodos de jQuery dão para encadear porque todos eles retornam um `jQuery` que é um objeto com a coleção apanhada no selector ou alterada caso o ultimo método tenha alterado. Pode confirmar consultando alguns deles na documentação: [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/), [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: @Anthraxis Já deu uma lida na [documentação do MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) sobre classes no ES6?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss esse link especifico que mando ainda não, mas é muito estranho como o javascript funciona, usar é fácil, o dificil é saber o que você ta fazendo D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É interessante pensar em J-query como um aliado do javascript em orientação a objeto, mas não faz nenhum sentido misturar J-query em coisas que não estejam relacionadas a manipulação de DOM e manipulação de eventos.

Pense em coisas como Herança, polimorfismo, abstração, encapsulamento. J-query só iria atrapalhar, até porque não passa de uma biblioteca que fornece os métodos da linguagem nativa.

Em relação a classe, há também um infinidade de modos de instancia-la, cada uma com sua particularidade.

Vale a pena ler [Desvendando a linguagem javascript](https://pt.slideshare.net/rodrigobranas/java-script-overview)

Answer (score 1):

Está correto. Porém faria a seguinte observação.
Para instancia, deve-se usar o `new Classe().init()`
Porém, não é a unica forma.
Você também pode usar como auxílio, o prototype. vai lhe ser útil.

Com relação a orientação a objetos. hoje eu não acredito que o js seja OO. Porém, acredito que ele faça uso de objetos e de forma cadenciada, o que potencializa o uso da linguagem.

Hoje acredito que a grande vantagem no JS está nesta forma "corrida" de programar.